# How to calculate the P(object) and P(class/object) for training images in YOLO object detection algorithm?

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection

I went through the YOLO paper and got to know the loss function and all. But what I could't understand is how to obtain above values for training images ? There is no clear explanation for that in their paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the paper:

**Confidence = P(Object)*IOU**

**Class-specific Confidence = P(Class_i|Object)**

note: IOU = IOU（Predict_Box, Gt_Box）

**P(Object)** is in {0, 1}, if the Predict_Box has zero IOU with Gt_Box, set P(Object) to 0, indicated background, otherwise, set it to 1.

**P(Class_i|Object)** is a conditional probability. If the Predict_Box has zero IOU with Gt_Box, P(Class_i|Object) should be 0 because it is not an object, other wise set it equivalent to IOU.

Comment: so the probability for the class is one hot encoded right?.